# "'float' is not subscriptable" in odeint

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I'm trying to implement coupled differential equations in Python, and as a new user I seem to be stuck at something. I used this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRMmiBMjP9o) as a guide to how to solve my ODEs, and looked into the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) to no available

This is where I define the function

```
def Burnout(t, y, m, nu, S0, V, delta, mu):
    S = y[0];

    E = [0 for i in range(0,m)]
    dEdt = [0 for i in range(0,m)]

    for i in range(0,m):
        E.append(y[i+1])

    P = y[m+1]

    dSdt = -nu*S*P*(S/S0)**V
    dEdt.append(nu*S*P*(S/S0)**V-m*delta*E[0])

    for i in range(1,m):
        dEdt.append(m*delta*E[i-1]-m*delta*E[i])

    dPdt = m*delta*E[m-1]-mu*P

    return [dSdt, *dEdt[0:m], dPdt]
```

Then, as in the tutorial, I define the initial conditions by

```
 S0 = N
 y0.append(S0)

 for i in range (0, m):
    E.append(0)
    y0.append(E[i])

 P0 = Z
 y0.append(P0)
```

where N and Z are previously defined things, and E was an empty array. When I finally call odeint(Burnout, y0, t, args = p), I get a 'float' object is not subscriptable pointing to my definition of S in my Burnout function. As I passed a list to odeint I'm kind of confused on why Python says I passed a float. Does anyone see what I did wrong? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Ok, now here is a minimal, complete and verifiable example that gives me the same error

import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

```
 def Burnout(t, y, m, nu, S0, V, delta, mu):

    S = y[0]

    E = [0 for i in range(0,m)]
    dEdt = [0 for i in range(0,m)]

    for i in range(0,m):
        E.append(y[i+1])

    P = y[m+1]

    dSdt = -nu*S*P*(S/S0)**V
    dEdt.append(nu*S*P*(S/S0)**V-m*delta*E[0])

    for i in range(1,m):
        dEdt.append(m*delta*E[i-1]-m*delta*E[i])

    dPdt = m*delta*E[m-1]-mu*P

    return [dSdt, *dEdt[0:m], dPdt]


V = 2.97
m = 26
delta = 1/6
mu = 1
nu = 10
S0 = 5

t = np.linspace(0,56,100)

y = [10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100]
p = (m, nu, V, S0, delta, mu)
print(odeint(Burnout,y,t,args=p))
```

Comment: Sounds like what is being passed in to `Burnout` as `y` is a `float`. I can't tell from the posted code why that is happening.

Comment: But I passed y0, which as you see in my second Blockcode was defined as an array.

Comment: I don't see any call to `Burnout` at all. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure `t` is an array as well? It's not `dt` as a float it needs to be an array of all values of `t`.

Comment: `out = odeint(Burnout, y0, t, args = p)`
I call it here. I believe `t` must be an array, but I'll look into my definition of it to be sure, thanks!

Comment: @Brunnun what is `t`? I'm pretty sure it's a float when it needs to be an array.

Comment: I realize omitting some things to not throw a bunch of random variables at you might have been useless considering `t` for example is very important. For reference, here it is `t = np.linspace(0,56,100)` and I'll edit the question with my whole code to be complete

Comment: I now edited to have the smallest amount of code that reproduces my error. I apologize for the clunkyness, literally signed up for Stack Overflow 10 minutes ago

Comment: you have `y` and `t` backwards. you need: `def Burnout(y, t, m, nu, S0, V, delta, mu):`

Comment: ......I'm embarassed, I didn't think the ordering would matter but of course it does. Thank you and I'm sorry for wasting your time

Comment: no worries.. I solved it with a debugger and probed the values of y and t inside the function before it called `S = y[0]`. It was apparent pretty fast that `y` was the first value of `t` and `t` was equal to `y0`. You should for sure find a good editor with an easy to use debugger so you can set breakpoints to pause your code where you need it and give you a live prompt to poke around at things.

Comment: I see! I'm using Jupyter just cause my PostDoc recommended it. I'm sure there's a debugger in it, I'll just search around. Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend spyder. Jupyter is pretty looking and good for demonstrations and presentations, but it is not good for developing code. If you really want to learn the language by heart, use a raw text editor and a terminal... There are actually quite a number of people who use notepad++ as their primary code editor.

Comment: I do prefer text and terminal, I usually code in C++ using Sublime. The thing is that I'm coding on Windows (since I'm having some problems with my Linux partition), and using the Windows terminal is a bit outlandish to me right now. But I definitely wanna work up to that!

Answer (score 0):

You ordered the arguments in your ode definition wrong. It is possible to have `t` before `y`, but then you must define `tfirst = True` [(see docs)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html).

Swapping the arguments in your definition of `Burnout` fixes the problem for me.

```
def Burnout(y, t, m, nu, S0, V, delta, mu):
   # ...
   # rest of function
   # ...
```

Alternately you can define the additional keyword `tfirst` in the `odeint` call:

```
odeint(Burnout, y, t, args=p, tfirst=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was dumb about that, but I'm glad y'all caught my mistake. Will be more careful in the future